# How to automatically close Java server?

Tags: java, timer, client-server, session-timeout

I need a way to automatically close the server program which runs by using some sort of timer. Till now this is what I got

```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end = start + 10 * 1000; // 60 seconds * 1000 ms/sec

    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(
                connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
        capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
        outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
        count = count + 1;

    }
    welcomeSocket.close();
```

Is this possible? Please help and don't down vote. I'm kinda a noob regarding client- server in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setSoTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) for that.

Typically, you'll set that with some value like 100 ms, enter a loop and call accept. When the timeout exception is thrown you'll check to see if its ok to exit or not and either fall out of the loop or keep going.

Then make sure you clean up the socket when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Run the code you have there in a Thread (named server in the code below), and then start another Thread like this to do an interrupt when you want to exit:

```
Thread server = {the one you have};
Thread timeout = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        long end = start + 10 * 1000;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(end);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //handle this
        }
        server.interrupt();
    }
}
timeout.start();
```

The socket.accept will now throw InterruptedException and bypass all your other code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are okay with `Threads`. Would still recommend you to have a look at the [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class.

You can create a `Timer`, which created a thread to close down your server. You can make your connection as a `final variable` and then use `synchronised` access to it to close it once `Timer` thread kicks in.